# How does LDAP user management subvert /etc/groups and /etc/password

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

This question is written from the perspective of an LDAP novice:

Standard linux ID credentials are stored in the /etc/passwd /etc/groups directories.

Does LDAP based authentication subvert the information in these folders?   Or does it simply update them on a regular basis?

I understand that LDAP based authentication can allow for universal IDs in a network of linux machines, but it is hard to find a simple explanation of *how* LDAP is leveraged to intercept logind and/or subvert the standard /etc/ based credentials, to provide network authenticated access into linux boxes.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP doesnt "subvert" anything.  Rather, it is a service which your OS canuse to authenticate.  The contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf reference different underlying sources..

Reading these posts:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch
- http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_ldap_authentication (see the reference to nsswitch.cont)

Gives a pretty intuitive understanding of the relationship between nsswitch.conf and the way ldap authentication gets turned on.